# UITextView with emoticons editing

Tags: ios, text, uitextview, emoji, emoticons

I am developing xmpp-client app. One of the features is sending smiles and user should have ability to edit its like usuall text. Emoticons editing in [Viber App](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/viber-free-phone-calls-text/id382617920?mt=8) is best example of what i want to implement.

I already tried three ways to solve problem:

- I create emoticon like usual UIImageView and place it as a subview on UITextView using current caret rect. I use 5 whitespaces as a text placeholder in text view. There are two problems: with placing emoticons on new line when inserting text in the middle(printing whitespace not make caret move to new line); when user placing caret using magnify glass, he can move caret through emoticon(through 5 whitespaces), as delegate method not called during this process.
- I have tried [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView). There are problems with caret position and resizing when new line should be added. And there are some rendering artifacts when using it one line size.
- I also have tried using UIWebView. But there were great problems with resizing based on text size and other artifacts with speed of response when becoming first responder.

May be some one could give me advice of really working solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really into rects and ranges mechanism of UITextView/UITextInput, but I try to give you an (untested) advice that maybe could achieve the expected result.

Built-in iOS emojis are simple characters, so we can follow the same path by building a custom font (or extend an existing one). 
We have two options:

- If you want to target **iOS 6.0** (that has native support for `NSAttributedString` in UIKit classes), you could try to build a custom font containing all the emoticons you need, and use it inside your `NSAttributedString` (attributed string can mix different fonts, font sizes, styles and so on).
- You could do something similar with **iOS 5**, but since you can't use `NSAttributedString` inside `UITextView` (so you are limited to just one font for the entire text) you should use a font that combines together the actual characters and the custom emoticons: so you should extend the font you want to use for typing, by adding all the emoticons to it. I don't know if this could have licenses implications, anyway.

Otherwise, you could always go much more low-level, implementing your own custom textView using [CoreText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html), but I think it would be a hard work.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I also start to think about font customization, but I actually don't know how to make full-colored bitmap glyphs in font like apple emoji.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate colourful images within a font on iOS?

Comment: I managed to create custom font with sbix table using custom png images. It perfectly works on OS X, but iOS declined to render glyphs which has only mapping to sbix table from font other then system version of Apple Emoji.In other words, if you set you custom font in UITextView to UILabel programatically and set text value as some emoji UTF symbol code, glyph from standard emoji font will be rendered even if in your custom font glyph presents for that UTF code.